# Calculation of the input values

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular9, angular10

I am working on a angular app in which I have a matInput field as shown in below code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-slider-simple-slider-example-dbyxqm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

User can enter positive or negative value. Suppose I have current value as 100 and user enter +5 or 5(user can use + symbol or can give positive number) I want my final output as 100 and if user enter -5 then I want my final output should be 95 and I want to display output immediately on screen. The problem I am facing with my code is :

1. Input is getting appended to 100 it is not doing any addition or substraction
2. I am not getting immediate output. I am able to display output if I click somewhere outside input field.

How can I resolve above two issues?

#### HTML

```html
<input matInput (change)="valueUpdated($event)">
my final value is {{myFinalValue}}
```

#### TypeScript

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Options } from 'ng5-slider';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public myFinalValue: number;

  valueUpdated(event) {
    this.myFinalValue = 100 + event.target.value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check [ask] and make sure you are presenting a [mcve] as codeblocks in your question. Stackblitz is great, but not enough, question becomes useless when the link dies...

Comment: You should change the event attribute `change` to `keypress` if you want to get immediate change when you press a key in the textbox.

Comment: it is not working with keypress. Could you please update add your code to my stackblitz or as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the input element returns the value as a string instead of a number.

You need to convert `event.target.value` to a number before adding the two.
You can use the shorthand `+event.target.value`, which will convert the value to a number (it's equivalent to `parseInt(<var>)`)

```js
valueUpdated(event) {
  this.myFinalValue = 100 + +event.target.value;
}
```

if you want the UI to update on every input change, you need to use the `(input)` event instead of the `(change)` event:

```html
<input matInput (input)="valueUpdated($event)">
my final value is {{myFinalValue}}
```

[Here's my fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-slider-simple-slider-example-gryunc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) of your stackblitz with the changes.

Comment: It is doing calculations but I am able to print result value after I click outside of input box. why is it so? Could you please have a look at my stackblitz if I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: @Jamie changed my answer to also make it update immediately.

Comment: @Jamie basically, `(change)` only triggers on inputs when the focus is lost or when you press `enter` while focused inside the input. That's why the value in the UI is not updating even though you changed the value. With `(input)`, the event triggers every time the user inputs something. `keyup` and `input` should be very similar. not sure what the difference exactly.